# DNN Navigation Menu Link Not Showing to Guests

Tags: navigation, dotnetnuke

I am trying to create a new menu link in DNN.

I have created the "Blog" page as a redirect to blog.example.com, I have permissions set to visible to all users, and the "Include in Menu" checkbox is marked.

Despite all of this, guest users on the site cannot see the nav menu link to our blog.

Comment: What happens if you make it a normal menu item (no redirect). Is it visible then?

Comment: @VDWWD Thanks for the reply, however, time was of the essence, and I dove straight into the database and set 'published' from 0 to 1. For the life of me, I could not find a 'publish' button anywhere on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went to our DNN database, and set 'published' for the page from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way: `Edit Page > Make Private` and then back to `Edit page > Make Public`.